# ASP.NET MVC and Strings doesn't give me compile time errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, process, compiler-errors

I'm a *big* fan of compilation errors.  I find the a lot easier to fix than runtime bugs.  I currently using the ASP.NET MVC framework and I find it has a lot of room for typos that the compiler won't catch.

For Example if I want to return the view `Data` from the `Index` action.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View("Data");
}
```

can easily be mistyped

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View("Dats");
}
```

and will not give an error till I run *that action*.

Has anyone devised a method of checking these sorts of things at compile time?  I've come up with two possible solutions:

- Creating a static class with all action names as constants, and using that for view names.  I would have a coding rule that says only use the constants.  The weakness with this if I change a view name I have to update the class.
- Lots of unit tests just to make sure every controller action returns a valid `ActionResult` and running them anytime I make a change.

What process have y'all implemented to help manage this risk?  Are there any add-ons or frameworks that mitigate this issue?

Comment: R# 5 helps you with this. It will not give you a error (might be able to configure that somehow), but you will see directly if there is a view with that name (you will get a underline). It will do the same if you use the string version of Url.Action() or any other of the built in helpers where it make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [T4MVC project](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC&referringTitle=Documentation) (which recently became part of [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/)) works to solve this issue.  From the documentation:

> T4MVC is a T4 template for ASP.NET MVC
>   apps that creates strongly typed
>   helpers that eliminate the use of
>   literal strings when referring the
>   controllers, actions and views. It
>   helps make your MVC code much more
>   maintainable, and gives you
>   intellisense where you normally would
>   not have any.

Comment: Does it work with the express versions of Visual Studio?